# Setting up Queue in Lumen Framework

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, lumen, laravel-queue

I'm trying to set up queue in Lumen using the guide from lumen page:
http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/queues

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BlastEmail extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    public function sendEmail()
    {
        [...CODE TO SEND EMAIL...]
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->sendEmail();
    }
}
```

and in My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Jobs\BlastEmail;
use App\Models\Blast;
use App\Models\Subscriber;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class BlastsController extends BaseController
{
    public function queue(Request $request)
    {
        $job = (new BlastEmail($email,$request->input('content'),$request->input('title')));
        $this->dispatch($job);
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    //
}
```

BaseController.php

```
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller; 
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;

class BaseController extends Controller {
     function someFunctionThatOtherGuyWrote()
     {
        // Some code that other guy wrote
     } 
}
```

And I got

> Undefined method App\Http\Controllers\BlastsController::dispatch

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, your `BlastsController` extends `App\Http\Controllers\BaseController` and not `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`.

You should change it to extend `Controlller` class changing `class BlastsController extends BaseController` into `class BlastsController extends Controller` because this class will finally uses `Laravel\Lumen\Routing\DispatchesJobs` trait that contains `dispatch` method

**EDIT**

After update you didn't show full `BaseController` file but it seems you extends wrong class. You extend `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` and you should extend `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

Comment: I got the "BaseController extends Controller" in BaseController.php. I believe it should be working right?

Comment: @YansenTan Please include then `BaseController.php` and `Controller.php` in your question

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got "Cannot use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController because the name is already in use in ... Controller.php". (I just update the question and add my BaseController.php and Controller.php).